# pointer to an array of Integers

Tags: c, pointers

What is the difference between `int *a[10]` and `int (*a)[10]`?

I suspect that since `[]` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator,
the first case will be an array consisting on 10 pointer variables storing the address of integer.
The 2<sup>nd</sup> case is the one which I am unsure what it does and why?

Answer (score 2):

`int *a[10]` declare `a` as an array of 10 pointers to `int`.
`int (*a)[10]` declare `a` as a pointer to an array of 10 `int`s.

Remember these two rules to decipher pointer declarations:

- **Always read declarations from inside out**: Start from innermost, if any, parenthesis. Locate the identifier that's being declared, and start deciphering the declaration from there.
- **When there is a choice, always favour [] and () over `*`**: If `*` precedes the identifier and `[]` follows it, the identifier represents an array, not a pointer. Likewise, if `*` precedes the identifier and `()` follows it, the identifier represents a function, not a pointer. (Parentheses can always be used to override the normal priority of `[]` and `()` over `*`).

For example:

```
int *a[10];      "a is"  
     ^  

int *a[10];      "a is an array of 10"  
      ^^^^ 

int *a[10];      "a is an array of 10 pointers"
    ^

int *a[10];      "a is an array of 10 pointers to `int`".  
^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

- `int *a [10]` - is declaring an array named `a` of 10 `int *`s.
- `int (*a)[10]` - is declaring a pointer named `a` to an array of 10 `int`s.